# Include new rows in autofilter range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am working with an excel 2007 worksheet that has the "filter" applied so that each column heading has a pull-down menu for sorting. When I add new rows to the end of the table by cut-n-paste from the last row, these new rows are not included in the sorting. I can't seem to get the newly added rows to be included in the filter range. I tried un-selecting and re-selecting the "filter" button and also tried the "reapply" button. The "clear" button is always greyed out. I can't seem to find any relevant help for this online anywhere. Not sure if it matters, but the heading row and the first column are set to be "sticky" (they don't scroll with the rest of the table.)

Comment: I eventually just deleted the file and started over. Works fine now. Wish I knew what caused that problem... Thanks anyway.

Comment: "sticky" is actually called frozen panes.  FYI.